# How can I override the Apache 404 status in PHP?

Tags: php, linux, apache, http

I have a PHP site set up using a 404 page to handle pretty URLs and some cacheing. This works quite nicely, and faster than the [usual htaccess redirect rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3160066/1154998) under heavy load.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /damncache/index.php
```

The problem is that Apache sets the HTTP status to 404 and I cannot seem to override it. Consequently when Google indexes the site all of those pages are not indexed (according to the Google Webmaster tools).

Here's how I am trying to override it at present:

```
header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . " 200 OK");
header("Status: 200 OK"); // for fast cgi
```

With this it works fine for humans/browsers, but Google apparently receives a 404 status and stops. Here is [an example](http://www.damninteresting.com/lucid-decapitation/).

It's hosted on a Dreamhost dedicated Linux server running PHP 5.3.x with FastCGI.

Comment: Why would you want a search engine to record pages that are `Not Found`? It's an inconvenience to users if they click a link with takes them to a 404.

Comment: @diggersworld that's not what he's doing, he's using 404 error document for *regular pages*. which is quite ... unorthodox.

Comment: @eis It _is_ unusual, but I was doing science! I had a hypothesis, tested it with experiment, and came to a conclusion. Basically the 404 page is a gateway PHP script that checks for a valid cached page, failing that tries to build the page based on the url, and failing that returns a 404 page/status. Apart from this Google quirk it's working splendidly...much faster than the old htaccess redirect way.

Answer (score 1):

http://web-sniffer.net/ reports a 200 OK header - have you given Google enough time to recrawl the pages?

If it has already removed them from the index, you may need to submit them again - it may pick them up by crawling other links, but a sitemap in webmaster tools is probably a good idea anyway.

Comment: Hmm...It's possible I suppose. The Google Webmaster Tools showed all these 404 errors a few days ago, so I revised my header() call to include the FastCGI method and marked all the 404 errors as resolved. Then the errors all reappeared in GWT today. But it's possible it's still in that gray reindexing area. I'll give it a little more time. Thanks for the link!